# Is it possible to create a flipcard using html+css only, without position absolute and maintain responsive design?

Tags: html, css

If anyone can provide suggestions without the use of positioning absolute, it would be most appreciated.

I have created some flipcards with the html and css below: the front ideally should be the image and when hovered over, the image flips revealing the text on the back. The text should fit within the confines of the image space as well as scaling both image and text as the screenwidth changes.
Does anyone know how to get this scaling to work?
Also, does anyone know how to get the flip animation to work so that there is no horizontal or vertical movement when you hover over the image?
Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .card_front {
            height: 25vw;
            width: 25vw;
        }

        .flip_card_flex {
            display: grid;
        }

        .card_body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: transform 1.5s;
        }

        .card:hover .card_body,
        .card:focus .card_body {
            transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            transition: transform 1.5s;
        }

        .card:hover .card_back {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .card:hover .front {
            display: none;
        }

        .card_front {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .card_back {
            transform: rotateX(-180deg) translate(0%, 0);
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

</html>
<!-- Flip cards-->
<div class="Tech_Title row">
    <h2 class="fs-2">example</h2>
</div>
<div class="flip_card_flex row justify-content-evenly pt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_body">
            <img class="card_front img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="html5_logo">
            <p class="card_back text-dark bg-light">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora perferendis consectetur, eos odit debitis rerum porro ad nobis quos velit.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card_body">
            <img class="card_front img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" alt="css3_logo">
            <p class="card_back text-dark bg-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam iste asperiores delectus molestiae a ducimus numquam sapiente, possimus quo. Eveniet, tempore adipisci saepe qui hic exercitationem ratione consectetur nostrum!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there are thousands of examples of flip cards on the web, have you done any research? and what don't you like about absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

This code needs customization but can help :

```css
  .flipcards {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

  }
  .flipcards .flipcard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;


  }
  .flipcards .flipcard:hover .flipcard__inner {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px -20px;
  }
  .flipcards .flipcard__inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
  }
  .flipcards .flipcard__inner .__front,
  .flipcards .flipcard__inner .__back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: var(--color2);
  }
  .flipcards .flipcard__inner .__front {
    z-index: 1;
    flex-flow: column;

  }

  .flipcards .flipcard__inner .__back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flipcards">
    <div class="flip_card_flex row justify-content-evenly pt-5">
    <div class="flipcard flipcard--red">
        <div class="flipcard__inner">
            <div class="__front">
                <img class="card_front img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="html5_logo">
            </div>
            <div class="__back">
                <p class="card_back text-dark bg-light">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora perferendis consectetur, eos odit debitis rerum porro ad nobis quos velit.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipcard flipcard--blue">
        <div class="flipcard__inner">
            <div class="__front">
                <img class="card_front img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" alt="css3_logo">
            </div>
            <div class="__back">
                 <p class="card_back text-dark bg-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam iste asperiores delectus molestiae a ducimus numquam sapiente, possimus quo. Eveniet, tempore adipisci saepe qui hic exercitationem ratione consectetur nostrum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```